# Should involve.. usage of the word involve

Tags: usage, passive-voice, active-voice

Is this grammatically correct?:

> I strongly agree that children should involve in group activities

I'm not sure if this option is better and more accurate:

> I strongly agree that children should be more involved in group activities

or

> I strongly agree that children should involve themselves in group activities

Answer (score 2):

Your first example is incorrect. Examples 2 and 3 are correct.

**Involve** in the active voice requires a direct object, as in example 3.

> The children should involve themselves/friends/teachers in group activities.

**Involve** can be used intransitively in the passive voice (as a participle that follows the verb **to be**), as in example 2.

You will find numerous examples and a detailed explanation of such usage at:

http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/to_be.htm